# If you use Spring dependency injection does the unit test require some Spring stuff?

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, spring

I completely understand, I think, how injecting a dependency of a class allows that dependency to be mocked and the class to be tested with the mocked version.

What I am not sure about is if you use @autowired to do this DI and write a junit test, will newing up the class be okay? That is, will the annotation simply be ignored and the constructor can be used normally?

If so, is there ever a case when you want to use Spring in the unit test to inject the mock? It seems to me that if you are writing a unit test, you want it to be as simple as possible and so would avoid involving Spring if you could.

Answer (score 1):

**Spring is not needed.**

You can create your tests with JUnit (As example) or another framework that let you mock elements. You only need to prepare your code to be tested. Maybe using JUnit inyection with annotations, parametrized constructor or setters to your class attributes.